# Isomorphism of the homology group to the associated cellular homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

at the moment I am learning a little bit algebraic topology.

So let $(H_\ast, d_\ast)$ be a ordinary homology theory satisfying the additivy axiom in the sense of the Eilenberg Steenrod axioms.

Let $X$ be a CW complex. Then we can define the cellular chain complex of X associated to the $(H_\ast, d_\ast)$ by $C_n^{cell} (X) = H_n(X^n, X^{n-1})$. The boundary operator is given by the boundary operator of the long exact sequence of the triple $(X^n, X^{n-1}, X^{n-2})$.
The homology of this chain complex is called the cellular homology associated to $(H_\ast, d_\ast)$ and is denoted by $H_n^{CW}(X)$.

I already proved the following theorem:

If A is a CW-subcomplex of X, then $C_\ast^{cell}(A) \subseteq C_\ast^{cell}(X)$ is a subcomplex.

Now we have an induced long exakt sequence of chain complexes and define the relative cellular homology $H_n^{CW}(X,A)$ by the homology of the quotient complex.

Now I want to prove, that there is an isomorphism
$H_n(X,A) \to H_n^{CW}(X,A)$.

I already understand the absolute case (see e.g. [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), p.140). But I do not know, how to extend this proof to the relative case.

My idea was to look at the long exact sequences an use the five lemma

$$
\begin{matrix}
 H_n^{CW}(A)&  \to & H_n^{CW}(X) & \to & H_n^{CW}(X,A) & \to & H_{n-1}^{CW}(A) & \to & H_{n-1}^{CW}(X)\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & & & \downarrow & & \downarrow\\
 H_n(A)&  \to & H_n(X) & \to & H_n(X,A) & \to & H_{n-1}(A) & \to & H_{n-1}(X)
\end{matrix}
$$

But I do not know how to define the map in the middle of the diagram above.

Thanks in advance, 
Felix

**Edit due to Connor Malin's Answer:**

I was able to prove that 
$$C^{cell}_{n}(X,A) \cong H_n(X^n/A^n, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1})$$
for all $n \geq 1$ and
$$C^{cell}_{0}(X,A) \cong H_0(X^0/A^0, A^0/A^0)$$
and the boundary operator is just the boundery operator from the long exact sequence of the tripel $(X^n/A^n, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1}, X^{n-2}/A^{n-2})$ resp. $(X^1/A^1, X^0/A^0, A^0/A^0)$

Now I want to adapt the absolute case to proof that $H_n(X/A, A/A) \cong H_n^{CW}(X,A)$.

So, I considered an aanalog diagram as in Hatcher (p.139):

**Edit due to Connor Malin's Answer:**

I was able to prove that 
$$C^{cell}_{n}(X,A) \cong H_n(X^n/A^n, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1})$$
for all $n \geq 1$ and
$$C^{cell}_{0}(X,A) \cong H_0(X^0/A^0, A^0/A^0)$$
and the boundary operator is just the boundery operator from the long exact sequence of the tripel $(X^n/A^n, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1}, X^{n-2}/A^{n-2})$ resp. $(X^1/A^1, X^0/A^0, A^0/A^0)$

Now I want to adapt the absolute case to proof that $H_n(X/A, A/A) \cong H_n^{CW}(X,A)$.

So I considered the following diagram as in Hatcher (p.139):

$$\begin{array}{rclrl}
&&&& 0\\
&&& \nearrow\\
&& H_n(X^{n+1}/A^{n+1}, A/A) &\cong& H_n(X/A, A/A) \\
&&\nearrow \\
&H_n(X^n/A^n, A/A)\\
\nearrow&&  \searrow\\
H_{n+1}(X^{n+1}/A^{n+1}, X^n/A^n) & \rightarrow & H_n(X^n/A^n, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1}) & \rightarrow &H_{n-1}(X^{n-1}/A^{n-1}, X^{n-2}/A^{n-2})
\end{array}$$

But I do not know how to choose ?. I already tried $H_n(X^n/A^n, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1})$ and $H_n(X^n/A^n, A^{n-1}/A^{n-1})$. But both seems not to work, since I was not able to show that $H_n(X^{n+1}/A^{n+1}, X^{n-1}/A^{n-1})$ or $H_n(X^{n+1}/A^{n+1}, A^{n-1}/A^{n-1})$ are isomorphic to $H_n(X/A, A/A)$.

And I also see, why this commutes with cellular maps of pairs of CW-complexes. But why does the connecting morphism commute with $d$, i.e. why does

$$\begin{matrix}
H_n(X,A) & \overset{d_n}{\rightarrow} & H_{n-1}(A)\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
H_n^{CW}(X,A) & \overset{d_n^{CW}}{\rightarrow} & H_{n-1}^{CW}(A)
\end{matrix}$$

commute?

Comment: The construction of cellular homology (as in  Hatcher) does not work for infinite CW-complexes for an **arbitrary** ordinary homology theory. At some point you have to invoke that the $n$-th homology group of a wedge of $k$-spheres is isomorphic to the sum of $n$-th homology groups of a $k$-sphere.For finite wedges this can be derived from the Eilenberg Steenrod axioms. But for infinite wedges this is an additional axiom (which is satisfied for singular homology).

Comment: Hi Paul Frost,

thanks for your remark. I just forgot to mention that i assumed also the additivy axiom. I just corrected my post above.

Answer (score 1):

From the identification of $X^n / X^{n-1}$ with a wedge of spheres, you can see that your relative chain complex $C^{cell}(X,A)$ is exactly $C^{cell}(X/A)$ with the exception of ${C_0}^{cell}$ which is generated by all the cells except the point $A$ was quotiented to. This means that ${H_*}^{CW}(X,A) \cong {\bar{H}_*}(X/A)$

Comment: Hi Connor Malin, thank you very much for your answer. This helped a lot. But I have some further questions. I will add them in my question above.